# Disallowing .htacces to certain folder not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
+public_html
    +libraries
    +webroot
        - access
        - css
        - images 
        - etcetera
    +.htaccess
```

I am currently trying to make the root `.htaccess` ignore the access folder in webroot/access/

It is currently forcing slash trails when I try to install a certain script that I need.

I have tried creating another .htaccess in the `access` folder and adding `RewriteEngine Off`, but it gives me a .404 error.

I have also tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/access/.*$` but it doesn't work either, what is the issue here?

Here is my .htaccess http://pastie.org/8602105

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule just below your first www rule:

```
RewriteRule ^access/?$ /webroot/access/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not fix it. I was waiting for you to reply actually, you're the only person in this place who replies to threads about htaccess. And you also wrote ReewriteRule xD

Comment: sorry for the typo, I corrected that. Do you have any other .htaccess in the system? As have you placed this rule just below www rule?

Comment: This is the only htaccess file, and yes right below RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

Comment: It continues to add slashes after I access site.com/access which becomes site.com/access/

Comment: oh slash is because of directory. Add this line on top of your .htaccess: `DirectorySlash Off`

Comment: Tried FF, IE and Chrome, still continues to add slashes when I tried to access oddify.co/access see it!:/

Comment: But I thought link is `/webroot/access` instead of `/access`

Comment: You actually were the one that helped me with this code, and you helped me to add a rewrite rule to hide the webroot folder as I did not want it to show on the browser header. It's in the pastie I posted.

Comment: ok got it and that explains why slash is appearing. See updated answer now. Now delete `RewriteRule ^webroot/access(/|$) - [NC,L]` line as well. Also remove `DirectorySlash Off` line.

Comment: It sends me to my 404 error page, I believe now it has to do with the .php being removed? would that be the issue?

Comment: Yes that's the reason. What content do you want to show for `/access`?

Comment: It's an admin section, only for those who has password can access it's contents. So it isn't important to see all the normal stuff that the rewrite rules are changing.

Comment: so you want to display `/webroot/access/index.php` in this case?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. But just for that folder.

Comment: ok try updated code. And make sure this is just below www rule.